# Code only runs by pressing F10 after a breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a MUD (Text based multiplayer RPG, in case you don't know) as a hobby. I had all my monster spawners each on their own thread, but quickly ran into issues keeping the code synchronized and realized it was way overkill anyway. I moved all the spawners (which handle their own spawns logic--so each spawner runs 3 or 4 monsters and replaces them if they die) to a single child thread of the main thread. There I have a "World" class loop over every spawner in the game to run its monster's logic. In theory nothing should really change. I barely modified the code. I just have it called from a single loop in 1 thread instead of each spawner looping for itself in its own thread.

Here's where things get weird and why I'm here asking for help (And I've already spent a few hours googling and troubleshooting). When I start the server nothing happens. I have debugging console writes everywhere and nothing shows up. So naturally I placed some breakpoints and while hitting F10 and walking through the logic (finding no issues) I start seeing the console writes showing up as I pass over them. If I sit there and press F10 forever I can essentially "manually" run the server... But as soon as I hit "Continue" to pause debugging everything stops. The server is still up, and I can set a breakpoint again and walk repeat the whole process.

What on earth!?

I've only been coding for about 10 years but I have never seen anything like this. Has anyone ever experience this before? I'll paste the code that runs the logic below, but again everything works perfectly if I just spam F10 via a breakpoint, lol.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that before the code refactor bringing everything back to 1 thread EVERYTHING WORKED PERFECTLY. So, having it suddenly not running, and only "working" if I spam F10 from a breakpoint is just weird.

**World instance code that manages the spawners**

```
    internal static void StartSpawnerThread() {

        SpawnThread = new Thread(DoSpawnerLogic) {
            Name = "SpawnerThread"
        };
        SpawnThread.Start();
    }

    internal static void DoSpawnerLogic() {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < SpawnerList.Count; i++) {
                SpawnerList[i].SpawnLogic();
            }

            if (NewSpawners.Count > 0) {
                SpawnerList.AddRange(NewSpawners);
                NewSpawners.Clear();
            }

            if (RemoveSpawners.Count > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < RemoveSpawners.Count; i++) {
                    SpawnerList.Remove(RemoveSpawners[i]);
                }
                RemoveSpawners.Clear();
            }
            // Regulates AI logic to roughly 30 ticks a second.
            //Thread.Sleep(33);
        }
    }
```

**Spawner code that handles spawning and executing the AI of the spawns**

```
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void StartSpawn(StreamingContext context) {

        _spawning = true;
        _spawns = new List<Mobile>();
        _deadSpawn = new List<Mobile>();
        World.NewSpawners.Add(this);
        ActiveSpawnerCount++;
        Console.WriteLine(ActiveSpawnerCount + " spawners active...");
        //Thread thread = new Thread(SpawnLogic);
        //thread.Name = "Spawner-" + ActiveSpawnerCount++;
        //World.SpawnThreads.Add(thread);
        //thread.Start();
    }

    internal void SpawnLogic() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        DateTime spawnTime = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));

        if (_spawning) {
            if (_spawns.Count < MaxNumberOfSpawn) {
                if (spawnTime < DateTime.Now) {
                    Mobile newMob = new Mobile(_spawnData[rand.Next(0, _spawnData.Length)], this);
                    _spawns.Add(newMob);
                    newMob.Stats.OnZeroHealth += QueueDestroyMob;
                    newMob.Move(_location);
                    World.Mobiles.Add(newMob.ID, newMob);
                    spawnTime = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} spawned in {1} at {2}",
                        newMob.FullName, _location, spawnTime));
                }
            }
            foreach (Mobile mob in _spawns) {
                if (!mob.IsDead)
                    mob.ExecuteLogic();
            }

            if (_deadSpawn.Count > 0) {
                lock (_deadSpawn) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _deadSpawn.Count; i++) {
                        DestroyMob(_deadSpawn[i]);
                    }
                    _deadSpawn.Clear();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if you changed "while (true)" to run like 10 times.. or 1000 times. It almost sounds like it's executing the loop and blocking the ui

Comment: Also, how are you communicating cross thread? Lists are not cross thread friendly.

Comment: I'll try setting a limit to the while loop. And as for cross thread communication that's a big component for what I'm refactoring this. It works perfectly prior to refactoring. I'm still learning about threading but for now I'm either copying small lists before operating on them or locking them where it won't kill performance.

Comment: Could there be a deadlock that occurs when you run at full speed, while stopping at the breakpoint gives the "other part" enough time to finish?

Comment: wouldve been nice if he wouldve updated the result here in the comments

Comment: @HeribertoLugo Tied having it only run 10, 100, and 1000 times, all with or without having the thread sleep for a short duration. Still the same behavior.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I'm not familiar with how that would be possible. Do you mean to say that two threads interacting with the same object, both locking, mean neither can proceed? If that was the case wouldn't stepping in/over during debug not advance the code?

Comment: @jtsmith1287 i dont think there is enough info/code to see the problem. for instance, i dont see where StartSpawnerThread is ever called. and again, lists are not thread safe. put the solution on github or something. i'd love to have a look and figure it out.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo This is 7 year old code and I've been actively learning. I'm thinking that instead of reviving my old code I'm just going to start over from scratch with a better design from the start and test driven.